# Swift Navigation Controller show on launch

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I create an app that can login, sign up and display list of users by using navigation controller and table view.

When user not logged in, then show the login page, otherwise show to list users page

But when app launching, the navigate controller always show first ether logged in or not. How can I hide that navigate on launching

**Edit:** initial controller is ViewController, navigation root view is the right one

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this I recommend you to take a different approach. Set your Users View Controller as the initial View Controller, and check if the user is logged in inside `viewDidAppear`. If they're not logged in, present the login page.

Comment: thank for reply my question. Is there another solution to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happend, I just restart my mac and it run perfectly as expect